How to disable specific rules from maven spotbug plugin
Maven spot bug plugin doesn't allow more than 80 characters or so. To comply with it, we have to wrap a specific piece of our code across 5 lines making it hard to read. We want to keep lambda expressions in a single line and keep the entire code with in 2 lines. Is there a way to tell maven to not check for line length / wrapping? I have tried @suppressFBWarnings and it didn't work.
Desired Format :
codeline1part1.codeline1part2
space...    space      .codeline2ExceedingLimit;
Current format after fixing spotbug line length error:
        codeline1part1.codeline1part2
                      .codeline2
                       .codeline3
                                    codeline4
                                                codeLine5
                                                            codeline6;
        


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
